# Detection of redirect

Tags: servlets

Is there a way to detect if a servlet was called because of a redirect?

Comment: where do you want to detect it. and why.

Comment: I could be wrong but you might check HTTP_REFERER

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is not exclusively limited to redirects. It contains (or rather, MAY contain) the URL of the page which lead to the requested page either through a redirect or a normal link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want to distinguish `sendRedirect` from a `forward`.

The only difference is that `sendRedirect` requests the client to issue a new request. So as part of this, headers would change. The hint for you is to compare the values of the request headers obtained by both redirect and forward and identify the difference.

Comment: The headers will be the same I would think. Why do you think they would be different? Forward happens in the server-side, so why would the headers change in the server side?

Answer (score 1):

I think not, because redirects are in no way different from normal page loads.